# Discord py command randomly works and doesnt

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord command that when triggered with "-meme" it will wait for the user to upload a image, then send the image URL back to them

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('-meme'):
        channel = message.channel
        author = message.author
        await channel.send('Upload a image')

        def check(m):
            return m.author == m.author and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send(msg.attachments[0].url)
```

Sometimes it will succeed and the bot sends the image url back and sometimes the bot will not return anything and gives this error, "IndexError: list index out of range"
I honestly have no idea what to try and why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `check`, try adding one for how many attachments are in the message:

```py
def check(m):
    return ... and len(m.attachments) != 0
```

The error is happening because the check is evaluating to `True` on ***any*** message that the author sends in the channel after that message, whether there's an attachment or not.

But adding that extra condition will only let the check evaluate to `True` if the user also uploads an attachment.

---

**References:**

- [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments)